# How to seamlessly transition into Interstitial iAd in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad

So my code for showing an interstitial iAd works, but it is slow to load the Ads. When the user is at my GameOver scene and they hit retry, it does a random number check and if the number matches the one I said, it uses an NSNotificationCenter to load my interstitial iAd.

```
 func interstitialAdChecker(){
    var randomAd = Int(arc4random() % 3)
    println(randomAd)

    if randomAd == 1 {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showInterstitialAdsID", object: nil)
    }
}
```

And in my game over scene, when the user taps replay, this is the code for transitioning scenes:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.replayButton {
            gameOverLogo.removeFromParent()
            replayButton.removeFromParent()
            yourScore.removeFromParent()
            highScore.removeFromParent()
            rateButton.removeFromParent()
            scoreBackground.removeFromParent()

            interstitialAdChecker()

            var scene = InstructionScene(size: self.size)
            let skView = view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

There is a 1 - 3 second delay between when the InstructionScene loads and when the Interstitial iAd is shown, so does anyone know how to make it seamlessly slide up from the bottom AS SOON as the user hits retry? The 1 - 3 second delay means the user might start the game and have an ad pop up mid gameplay which is no good. Thanks!

Comment: Try doing your random number check ahead of time, and then if you need to present the advertisement, do so.

Comment: I did that, but there's still a lag for when the ad is shown after transitioning scenes. I've seen apps where the second you hit retry, an interstitial ad popped up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the simulator or an actual device to test on? If you are using the simulator there can be a delay in showing ads from my experience.

If you are testing on your device then you should try delay your scene transition until the insterstitialAd has been handled by the user. You could set a bool for when the ad is showing so you don't transition. Then when the user cancels the ad the transition takes place.

Comment: I found a solution that lets the ad preload every time, that was the problem. It had to load the ads when it was called creating a delay.